# How do I allow my local web page access to LocalStorage in Brave Browser?

Tags: cookies, local-storage, brave, brave-browser

By default, Brave is blocking all 3rd party cookies, which is fine, however, I want to work on a local project which uses LocalStorage but I get the following error.

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.`

I don't want to turn 3rd party cookie blocking off, which does circumvent the problem, but I'd rather just whitelist local file access (doesn't allow whitelisting `file://` protocol).

Is it even possible to get this working without turning off the global "block all 3rd party cookies" setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is 2 ways you can achieve this. Probably also depends how you run your project. I use VS Code and when I run my projects in Brave I got that error. My files were just in a dev directory not in the wwwroot directory.

1. First option (recommended in my opinion)

   - Go to: Setting->Additional Settings->Privacy and Security->Site Settings->Cookies
   - In the "Allow" section add: "localhost" and "127.0.0.1"
     [image: Preferred option]
2. Second option (not recommended, as you also stated you don't want to do this)

   - Go to: Settings->Shields->Cookie Control
   - Select "Allow all cookies"
     [image: Not recommended option]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I actually figured I had to whitelist in the Cookies settings but I guess I needed to leave out the port, as I had "127.0.0.1:8080".

Comment: Whitelisting localhost and 127.0.0.1 is not working for me in current version of Brave (1.4.96). Switching cookie control shield to Allow all cookies does work. Same goes for Chrome (80.0.3987.132) if Block third-party cookies is on. Annoying since most browsers are likely to turn off third-party cookies by default in future.

Answer (score 3):

You can whitelist `file:///*` in `brave://settings/content/cookies`

Sadly it doesn't seem possible to make this rule more specific to only allow *some* local web pages access to cookies. And even worse, ***all*** local web pages share cookies with each other.

But for testing purposes it should be fine.

Obviously it would make more sense to setup a local web server though.

Comment: This was what I was searching since I'm checking for local file system. The clue was the "*" ! :) thanks!